# material-ui: how do I npm install master?

Tags: material-ui

How do I npm install the master?

I've tried @latest, @next, & @master.

```
@latest installs 0.15.1
@next installs 0.15.0-beta.2
@master throws an error
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can always install the npm package from its repository:

`npm install https://github.com/callemall/material-ui`

Comment: I tried this but I get this result: `"material-ui-build": "git+https://github.com/callemall/material-ui.git",` notice the `material-ui-build` How do I keep it as `material-ui` I'm having problems with my existing codebase where `material-ui` is used to import the package.

Comment: @JohnnyQ `material-ui-build` is the new name of the Material UI npm package as ou can see here https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/package.json#L2